# Regular expression restricting unwanted ones as well

Tags: java, regex

I had written a regular expression to not allow duplicate words similar to `SU MOTO` in a text area.The idea is to restrcit words that are similar as shown here

```
SU    MOTO
 SUMOTO 
'       SU          MOTO '
```

but now it is also restricting

```
'SUMOTO1' 
'4 SU MOTO'
```

which are considered to be valid and can be allowed.

The regex is

```
 String pat =   "\\bSU(\\s*\\b\\w*\\b\\s*){0,5}MOTO(\\s*\\b\\w*\\b\\s*){0,5}";
```

Please help

**EDIT**

invalid ones:
spaces before or after the word `SU MOTO`
like

```
'                   SU             MOTO'
SU                      MOTO
```

Following are valid ones

```
4 SU MOTO
SU88888MOTO
SUMOTO566
```

Comment: please define the rules : like any string consisting only the characters SUMOTO in that order ( spaces not considered ) are rejected . or give examples - are the following strings valid ? 'SU  <5 spaces>        MO   TO' , 6SUMOTO , SUMOTOO , sumOTO , 'SU      <6 spaces>          MOTO'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
^\\s*SU\\s*MOTO\\s*$
```

(If not, say what string it is matching/not matching)

Comment: No i guess now even SU   MOTO  SUMOTO is failing