# How to restrict the lower case words as well on a regex that is been using

Tags: regex

This is an extension to earlier question [Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435437/regular-expression-restricting-unwanted-ones-as-well) which restricts all required but not lower case ones like   `' su moto'` Can we modify to restrict the lower case word of the same 
Thanks.

**EDIT**
whoa rubbed the wrong shoulders !!! Actually the question is straight
I need to restrict for word
`SU MOTO` in my application.For that I am using the regex `'^\\s*SU\\s*MOTO\\s*$'`.This works fine but lower case is still a problem.

Can someone help me with this

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
(?-i)^\s*SU\s*MOTO\s*$
```

Will match `SUMOTO`, but not `sumoto`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#([A-Z0-9_-]*)#
```

That will catch all uppercase letters, numbers, underscore and dash.

I'm not really sure what you're trying to say.